# Get proper height for UItableViewCell with UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to get dynamic height for my cell that sometimes have one line, two-three lines of text. Problem is, that this function (from http://www.raywenderlich.com):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static UILabel* labelTitle;

    if (!labelTitle) {
       labelTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];
       labelTitle.text = @"test";
    }

    labelTitle.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];

    [labelTitle sizeToFit];

    return labelTitle.frame.size.height * 1.7;
}
```

It gets a static height that fits for all cells. I want a dynamic height that depends on the content in UILabels. And how to achieve this with UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle?

Comment: -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: But... I'm using it already.

Comment: Take a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights - there is a git hub project that walks through just how to do this by rendering the cell.  Works great as long as you don't have a lot of cells (around 1000). https://github.com/caoimghgin/TableViewCellWithAutoLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sizeToFit work you have to set the lines of your label to 0;

```
// width of the testlabel should be same for the label you are using to show in Cell
UILabel *testLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
testLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // you need to do this
testLabel.text = @" Your text here ";
[testLabel sizeToFit];
```

Now you can use the height of the label.

```
CGFLoat height = testLabel.frame.size.height + margin; // add margin if you want a float value
```

Also make sure to use sizeToFit for the label in **- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath**

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: Close! The cells look great, but three cells have to small height.. how is that even posible?

Comment: @tomqz if you specifically want 3 rows to look small, you can play with that Margin.  for ex : if(indexpath.row = 1) margin = 10; else margin = 20.

Comment: I get the data dynamically and that will not work for me. I checked your post again, and i found that I was implementing UILabel CGrectMake() wrong. I fixed it and it's working great. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, the larger of the text labels is accessed via the `textLabel` property and the smaller via the `detailTextLabel` property.

So probably like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static UITableViewCell *cell;
    static UILabel *label;

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Your Identifier"];
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 100);
        label = cell.detailTextLabel;
    }

    CGSize size = [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(label.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    return size.height;
}
```

Alternatively, inherit the UITableViewCell yourself, and draw the text there. The Cell code will be something like this:

```
@interface YourCell : UITableViewCell
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *text;
    + (CGFloat) heightForCellWithText:(NSString *)text;
@end
```

Cell implementation:

```
#import "YourCell.h"

@interface YourCell()

@end

static NSMutableParagraphStyle *textStyle;
static UIFont *textFont;

@implementation YourCell

+(void)initialize {
    textStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    textStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    textStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    textFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
}

-(void)setText:(NSString *)text {
    _text = text;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

#define TEXT_ORIGIN_X 20
#define TEXT_ORIGIN_Y 20
#define TEXT_SIZE_WIDTH 200

#define CELL_MARGIN TEXT_ORIGIN_X * 2

+ (CGFloat) heightForCellWithText:(NSString *)text {
    return [self heightForText:text] + CELL_MARGIN;
}

+ (CGFloat )heightForText:(NSString *)text {
    NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
    context.minimumScaleFactor = 1;
    return [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(TEXT_ORIGIN_X, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                       attributes:@{
                                    NSFontAttributeName: textFont, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:textStyle
                                    } context:context].size.height;
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    [self.text drawInRect:CGRectMake(TEXT_ORIGIN_X, TEXT_ORIGIN_Y, TEXT_SIZE_WIDTH, [self.class heightForText:self.text]) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:textFont, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:textStyle}];
}

@end
```

And your cell height calculation will be

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [YourCell heightForCellWithText:@"Test"];
}
```

Comment: I was using sizeWithFont earlier, now it's deprecated and i was wondering how to replace it.

Comment: Hey, I have updated the answer. I hope it is useful to you. In my project I have always used drawRect when dynamic height needs to be calculated. Maybe it will be a overkill for for a text value, but suppose you needs to render the cell using quite a few labels it will be handy.

Comment: I found the solution, but your answer will gonna help me later. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Sizing methods (`sizeWithFont`, `sizeToFit`) is very error-prone on `iOS7`.
I suggest using `sizeThatFits`. It is not perfect when I was using it, it cuts the last line if the last line has only one word: to overcome this issue, you should decrease its maximum width argument while frame of your UI field stays same.

Answer (score 0):

Each cell does get it's proper sizes when `layoutSubviews` is called for said cell.  It unfortunately doesn't get called when the cell is created.

You can use a slightly delayed `setNeedsLayout` for the cell to re-layout itself so you can get the proper sizes.